# how to fetch data from url using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have link generated from rest Api console 
this is the link:
https://SomeThing/rest1/order2/getOrders
and i have token generated from the same rest Api console
now i can make post by ajax ang get the data but i want to fetch this data
this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.post(
      "https://SomeThing/rest1/order2/getOrders",
      { token: "Token" },
      function(a, b) {
       <----what i should use --->
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: I deleted my original post, so it's _somehow_ gone and posted updated answer which does not have token in its history. Is that OK approach @AdamAzad?

Comment: @FanaticD, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news is that you are very close, bad news is that you leaked your token and will have to regenerate it now.

I would replace `function(a,b,)` just with `function(data)` and accessed data retrieved from called REST endpoint through the variable `data`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $.post(
          "https://www.tesetturpazari.com/rest1/order2/getOrders",
          { token: "<token>" },
          function(data) {
             console.log(data);
          }
        );
      });
});
```

When you then press F12 (or other hotkey used to open developer console in your browser), you can go through data retrieved from remote server and figure out how to further process your data based on its structure. It comes back in [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which is very easy to process in Javascript.

OP further explained the need to render data to div that already exists on site (in the comment on the answer that was deleted), solution is to update callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $.post(
          "https://www.tesetturpazari.com/rest1/order2/getOrders",
          { token: "<token>" },
          function(data) {
             // Possibly before displaying it all, do some preprocessing here over the data variable
             // Replace 'mydiv' with ID of an element where you want to show data
             $("#mydiv").html(data)
          }
        );
      });
});
```

**Note:** Please regenerate and replace your token.
**Note 2:** I repost this answer so I can remove the original one where I managed to duplicate access token, sadly.

Comment: Thank you it's usefull answer